# MySQL: For ORDER BY calls (different fields), do I create an index for each field?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

A quick question. I have a simple table with this structure:

```
USERS_TABLE = {id}, name, number_field_1, number_field_2, number_field_3, number_field_4, number_field_5
```

Sorting is a major feature, one field at a time at the moment. Table can have up to 50 million records. Most selects are done using the "id" field, which is the primary key and it's indexed.

A sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE id=10 ORDER BY number_field_1 DESC LIMIT 100;
```

The question:

Do I create separate indexes for each "number_field_*" to optimize ORDER BY statements, or is there a better way to optimize? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no silver bullet here, you will have to test this for your data and your queries.

If all your queries (e.g. WHERE id=10) returns few rows, it might not be worth indexing the order by columns. On the other hand, if they return a lot of rows, it might help greatly.

If you always order by atleast one of the fields, consider creating an index on that column, or a compound index on some of these columns - keep in mind that if you have a compound index on (num_field_1,num_field_2) and you order only by num_field_2 , that index will not be used. You have to include the leftmost fields of the index to make use of it.

On the other hand, you seem to have a lot of different fields you order by, the drawback of creating an index on each an every one of them is your indexes will be much larger, and your inserts/deletes/updates might start to get slower.

Basically - there is no shortcut. You'll have to play around with which indexes works best for your queries and tune accordingly, while carefully analyzing your queries with [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure if sorting 50k records returned counts as a lot or a few. I think a lot. I will definitely use the EXPLAIN function to check.

Comment: 50k would probably count as a lot.